# Problems with Core Graphics on Iphone 7 to generate PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pdf, core-graphics

When I generate a PDF, the file appears like a big gray rectangle, this occurs just on iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus. I am not able to debug, because I don't have the iPhone 7 device. I could reproduce this just on TestCloud, on simulator everything works fine. The suspecting is that the problem is on Core Graphics. Someone had this problem?

Comment: could you please provide some code of how you display and store

Comment: Sorry David, just saw your comment now, thanks :) Already solved!!

Comment: how you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Changing [self.webView.layer renderInContext:currentContext] for [self.webView drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.webView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:true] it works perfectly !!